# Well Fitted/Custom Fit armor perks: If the armor type of the shield is different, will it affect these perks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently did [Peryite's quest](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Only_Cure) and got this really bad-ass shield, [Spellbreaker](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Spellbreaker#Spellbreaker). However, its armor type is Heavy and I concentrated my armor perks on the Light Armor perk tree, and this includes the '[Custom Fit](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Light_Armor#Skill_Perks)' perk (25% Armor bonus if wearing all Light Armor).

If I'm wearing all Light Armor, while wielding a 'Heavy Armor' shield like Spellbreaker, will I still get the Custom Fit perk bonus?

Also, is this the same case with similar perks like Wind Walker/Tower of Strength (Stamina regenerates 50% faster in all Light Armor / 50% less stagger when wearing only Heavy Armor) and Matching Set (additional 25% Armor bonus if wearing a matched set of Armor - assuming that the player has a matching set of armor, except for the shield, which is a different armor type).

Comment: I have a suggestion to this I suppose. If you wear all light armour (i.e. remove that shield and replace it with something else) does the perk show up in the "Active Effects" tab under the Magic menu? I suppose from there, if it does, you could wield the shield and then see if it still turns up.

Comment: @IttyBrittyGirlGamer I tried this but it appears that the 'Active Effects' tab is bugged. It shows active effects for armor that I'm not currently wearing, and even if I'm wearing all-light armor, including the shield, it doesn't show the 'Custom Fit' perk as an active effect. I guess I want to know the mechanics of this, as it was designed, in a non-buggy Skyrim.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just tested this out on my character and can safely say that no, the shield being Heavy Armor will not remove the bonuses received from Custom Fit, Wind Walker, or Matching Set. Those bonuses are applied as long as you have Light Armor equipped to your Head, Chest, Hands, and Feet. So, boots, gloves, helm, and armor. The shield has nothing to do with those perks, so you're good!

Comment: I also would like to add that a Heavy Armor shield won't be affected by the '[Unhindered](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Light_Armor#Skill_Perks)' perk too (*Light Armor weighs nothing and doesn't slow you down when worn*). You'll be slowed down even if you have the Unhindered perk and wearing all light armor, except for a Heavy Armor shield. This could also be the case for Heavy Armor's 'Conditioning' (*Heavy Armor weighs nothing and doesn't slow you down when worn*) perk, when used with a Light Armor shield

Answer (score 3):

No, shields do not count towards armor sets. However, if, for example, you were a light armor user with all the light armor perks, heavy armor shields would not receive any bonuses from Agile Defender.